# How to get data inside a Promise Value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue-router

I'm trying to get the role of a User in my router.js file so that I can create Vue-Router Navigation Guards.

If the User's role is equal to candidate he can see all of the routes with this `requiresAuthCandidate` that I added to my candidate routes, in the meta field. I will then to the same thing for Employers. Right now, candidates can see employer's routes and employer's can see candidate's routes. This should not happen.

Bascially I want to do something like this.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{

    if (to.meta.requiresAuthCandidate) {
        if (auth.getProfile().role === 'candidate') {
            next({
               name: "home"
            });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }

});
```

When I `console.log(auth.getProfile());` I get a Promise and then inside a PromiseValue and then inside some data. The problem is if I try console logging the data like this `console.log(auth.getProfile().data);` I get `undefined`. Below is a screenshot of my data. Any idea why I can't access this data like normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `async/await` to get the promise resolved content

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) =>{

if (to.meta.requiresAuthCandidate) {
    const user = await auth.getProfile()
    if (user.role === 'candidate') {
        next({
           name: "home"
        });
    }
} else {
    next();
}
```

});

Comment: So I'm able to access the User's role now. But am I doing these guarded routes wrong? Right now anytime I click on my Sidebar Nav link to go to a candidate route it redirects me to the Home page, instead of allowing me to go to that specific route/page.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know your base code but as much I know

- **your auth.getprofile() return promise**

  you have to wait for a response then you can get data object to access your role element

  > like:  function  async(){ const myuser= await
  >   auth.getProfile(); // introduced in ES2016(async await) myuser.role; }

Answer (score -2):

When a function returns a promise, you can use the "await" keyword to wait for the result of the promise before proceeding.

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) =>{

    if (to.meta.requiresAuthCandidate) {
        // If auth.getProfile() returns a promise, you need to use await
        const profile = await auth.getProfile();

        if (profile.role === 'candidate') {
            next({
               name: "home"
            });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }

});
```

Comment: you can't use `await` without `async`

Comment: Yeah I missed that.